# Storing void pointers in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, zeromq

I'm getting segmentation fault on code that is trying to initialize a struct of pointers to 0mq context and socket. The commented out code in the main method works, but it's only using local variables. I would like to initialize them and pass them around in a struct, but my google foo is failing me on how to do this properly.

```
#include "zhelpers.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <zmq.h>

struct publisher{
    void *handle;
    void *context;
};

void init_publisher(struct publisher *p);
void destroy_publisher(struct publisher *p);
void publish(struct publisher *p,char *msg);

void init_publisher(struct publisher *p)
{
    p = (struct publisher *)malloc(sizeof(struct publisher));
    p->context = malloc(sizeof(void *));
    p->handle = malloc(sizeof(void *));
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *handle = zmq_socket(context,ZMQ_PUB);
    zmq_bind(handle, "tcp://*:5556");
    zmq_bind(handle, "ipc://feed.ipc");
    p->context = context;
    p->handle = handle;
}

void destroy_publisher(struct publisher *p)
{
    zmq_close(p->handle);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(p->context);
    free(p->handle);
    free(p->context);
    free(p);
}

void publish(struct publisher *p,char *msg)
{
    s_send(p->handle, msg);
}

int main(void)
{
/**
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *publisher = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    int rc = zmq_bind(publisher, "tcp://*:5556");
    assert(rc == 0);
    rc = zmq_bind(publisher, "ipc://weather.ipc");
    assert(rc == 0);
    printf("Started Weather Server...\n");

    srandom((unsigned) time (NULL));
    int zipcode, temperature, relhumidity;
    zipcode = randof(100000);
    temperature = randof (215) - 80;
    relhumidity = randof (50) + 10;

    char update[20];
    sprintf(update, "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity);
    s_send(publisher, update);
    zmq_close(publisher);
    zmq_ctx_destroy(context);
*/

    struct publisher *p;
    init_publisher(p);
    printf("Setup pub\n");

    srandom((unsigned) time (NULL));
    int zipcode, temperature, relhumidity;
    zipcode = randof(100000);
    temperature = randof (215) - 80;
    relhumidity = randof (50) + 10;
    char update[20];
    sprintf(update, "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity);
    publish(p,update);
    printf("Published Message\n");

    destroy_publisher(p);
    printf("Destroyed publisher\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid void pointers - that has a certain ring about it

Comment: [`p = (struct publisher *)malloc(sizeof(struct publisher));` ---> `p = malloc(sizeof(struct publisher));`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495) One problem is that you don't check if `malloc()` did not return `NULL`. Another problem is that you don't know where exactly the code crashes, use a debugger.

Comment: @iharob it's crashing in the zeromq code.  But the calls to actually initialize the void pointers are identical in both cases. So it appears to me that i'm not setting up the struct correctly, because it does not throw any faults if I do all the work in the main method (the commented out code).

Comment: I would recommend just returning a "struct publisher *" from your init_publisher method. If you really don't want to do that, you'll have to pass a pointer-to-pointer (struct publish **p) in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the passed pointer and the pointer you `malloc()`ed are not the same. The passed pointer contains the same address of your original pointer, presumably an invalid address, but the addresses of the poninters them selves are different because in [c](/questions/tagged/c) you can only pass a variable by value and hence, the pointer is copied.

That means that when you reassign `p` inside the function, the `p` from outside the function is unaltered. It would be different if it was allocated outside and you just use the function to access it's members.

You also don't need to `malloc()` every pointer you want to use, the thing is that it must point to a valid address before dereferencing it. When you want to request new uninitialized memory then you use `malloc()` otherwise you just make the pointer point to a valid address so that dereferencing it is defined, one example of using a pointer without `malloc()`ing it is

```
int *pointer;
int value;
value = 4;
pointer = &value; // Now `pointer' points to `value's` address
*pointer = 3;
printf("%d\n", value);
```

One way to write the function would be

```
int
init_publisher(struct publisher **pp)
{
    struct publisher *p;
    *pp = malloc(sizeof(struct publisher));
    if (*pp == NULL)
        return -1;
    p = *pp;
    p->context = zmq_ctx_new();
    p->handle = zmq_socket(context,ZMQ_PUB);
    if (p->handle != NULL) /* Just in case, do not dereference a NULL pointer */
    {
        zmq_bind(p->handle, "tcp://*:5556");
        zmq_bind(p->handle, "ipc://feed.ipc");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then you could use it like this

```
struct publisher *p;
if (init_publisher(&p) != 0)
    do_something_there_was_an_error();
/* Continue using `p' */
```

Note that the funcion is returning a value indicating whether allocations succeeded or not. Normally `malloc()` will not fail, but that doesn't mean that you should ignore the possible failure.

What I mean when I say if you allocate `p` first, is that if you instead do this

```
struct publisher *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
if (p == NULL)
    return handle_error();
init_publisher(p);
```

then `init_publisher()` could be

```
void
init_publisher(struct publisher *pp)
{
    void *context;
    void *handle;
    p->context = zmq_ctx_new();
    p->handle = zmq_socket(context,ZMQ_PUB);
    if (p->handle != NULL) /* Just in case, do not dereference a NULL pointer */
    {
        zmq_bind(p->handle, "tcp://*:5556");
        zmq_bind(p->handle, "ipc://feed.ipc");
    }
}
```

which is probably what you was trying to do.

Comment: Yup, your last example was what I was thinking in my head. But couldn't quite get there. I commented on Mike's answer and I think the real issue was me not understanding that even a pointer is passed by value and won't be updated inside of the method call if you change it. I was assuming that it was passed by reference, probably due to using C# most of the time and not having to worry about that (except for with value types of course). Structs != classes. Got it :)

Comment: Also, unlike [tag:c#] there is no automatic memory handling in [tag:c], no garbage collector, nothing like that. So be careful to call `free()` but also, to ensure that you have succesfuly allocated memory when you call `malloc()`.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be nothing in this code that would make it crash.  (Assuming you know how all your `zmq_...` stuff works.)

It would have helped if you told us precisely where the error occurs, but my guess would be that the error occurs *outside* of this code.

You see, you are passing `struct publisher *p` to your `init_publisher()` function, but then you are allocating memory for `p` inside that method, (which makes passing `p` pointless,) and then you are not returning `p`.  As a result, the code that calls `init_publisher()` probably expects `p` to be initialized, but it is not.  The memory pointed by `p` is just allocated and leaked locally within your `init_publisher()` function.

So, instead of passing `p`, just have the function declare it and return it.

Alternatively, if the caller has already allocated `p`, then do not allocate it all over again from within `init_publisher()`.

---

<sup>Please also note that the statements `p->context = malloc(sizeof(void *));` are unnecessary and they are leaking small amounts of memory, because you proceed to overwrite these struct members.</sup>

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted, it's accurate. Back to 0.

Comment: @DanielSloof well, I had written "there appears to be nothing wrong in this code", which is technically incorrect, I changed it to "there is nothing in this code that would make it crash".

Comment: I didn't downvote, I would imagine it was due to the "completely pointless statements" part. I switched to returning the pointer from the init_publisher method and it works. I guess I was confused because I assumed if you pass a pointer to something into a method and do a malloc, then that will actually keep the memory when it returns.

Comment: Matt, it will keep the memory.  But `p` is passed *by value*, so the caller never sees this memory.  If `p` is `NULL` in the context of the caller before the call, `p` will *remain* `NULL` in the context of the caller after your function returns.

Comment: Ah, the by value part was the part I was missing. That's what happens when you are used to pass by reference languages :) Thanks for the help.